# Design Pattern or Architecture help for console app

Tags: c#-4.0, design-patterns, soap-client, n-tier-architecture

I am working on App that does below stuff.

1. Import records from excel file and bulk dump to the sql server database.
2. Then I run store procedure to preform some database level checks.
3. Then I grab records and inject to third party Using SOAP api.
4. I keep all the log for each step and save to database.

I have divided stuff into 3 different classes.

1. excel import - does validation of excel sheet, validate data, sql bulk insert to database.
2. CodeInjectionPros.cs - this is class that handle massaging database and prepare records that need to go to SoapApi. and in same class doing injection and update status to mydb of each record that inserted into soap api.
3. Loggger.cs - when i start excel import - i create object of this class. start adding line at every step where i needed. when whole process end. i mean saving to soap api completed , then i made one call to database to save all details

I need to identify best practice to do that. Any help? Let me know if I need to post code as well?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can take a look at [Multi layered architecture](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilayered_architecture). Your application seems that could use the most common tiers:

- Presentation layer (a.k.a. UI layer: today it's

  > console app,

but in future you can add web, Win forms or etc.)

- Application layer (a.k.a. service layer: a place for your

  > SOAP API

service)

- Business layer (a.k.a. business logic layer:

  > Excel import and validation

in your case)

- Data access layer (a.k.a.

  > SQL

persistence layer , networking and logging  services which are required to support your business layer).

Once you are clear with the architecture, you can design the lower level.

On your presentation tier, you may decide to use a separated presentation pattern (a type of layered design style), such as [Model-View-Controller](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647343.aspx), for your interaction model.

For the bisiness tier, you can use Application [Facade](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/767154/Facade-Design-Pattern-Csharp) or some other of the [relevant patterns.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee658103.aspx#PatternMap)

In the Data access tier a good fit will be the [Data mapper pattern](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Data-Mapper-Design-Pattern-50ad1c32), since it give you layer between objects and the database structure that is used to move data from one structure to another while keeping them independent. Other related [patterns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee658127.aspx) to look at.

Comment: Welcome to the StackOverflow @Amrik, please remove the 'Thanks' comment. According to the site policy Good answers are voted up and rise to the top. The person who asked can mark one answer as "accepted".